# Spring mongo agregation returns empty List

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation

I have 160.000 data in my collection and I have to show some metrics about this data depending on a field. So I think I could group these data according to my "domain" field and get the summerized data from db.

I created a custom repository and a model for grouped data and run the bellow code but result is always empty however if I use the logged pipeline on robo3t I get what I want. 

Any Help is appreciated.

```java
//customRepository
@Service
public class EventRecordRepositoryCustomImpl implements EventRecordRepositoryCustom {

    private final MongoTemplate mongo;

    @Autowired
    public EventRecordRepositoryCustomImpl(MongoTemplate mongo) {
        this.mongo = mongo;
    }

    @Override
    public List<EventRecordCounts> query(String[] statuses) {
        //MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(new Criteria("status").not().in(Arrays.asList(statuses)));
        GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group("domain").sum("relatedRecordCount").as("totalRelatedEventCount").count().as("totalMainEventCount");
        AggregationOptions aggregationOptions = Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().explain(true).build();

        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation( group).withOptions(aggregationOptions);

        AggregationResults<EventRecordCounts> result = mongo.aggregate(aggregation, mongo.getCollectionName(EventRecord.class), EventRecordCounts.class);
        return result.getMappedResults();
    }
}
```

```java
//my collection: all getter and setters are provided
@Document(collection = "event_record")
public class EventRecord extends BaseModel {

    private ObjectId collectorId;

    @Indexed
    private String recordNumber;

    @Indexed
    private String status;

    private Long createdAt;

    @Indexed
    private Long updatedAt;

    private Long finishedAt;

    private String responsible;

    private String responsibleUserName;

    private String group;

    private String type;

    private String importance;

    private String summary;

    private Integer relatedRecordCount;

    @Indexed
    private String domain;
      }
```

```java
//Expected output model: all getter and setters are provided
public class EventRecordCounts {

    @Field("_id")
    private String _id;

    private String domain;

    private long openMainEventCount;

    private long openRelatedEventCount;

    private long totalMainEventCount;

    private long totalRelatedEventCount;
}
```

switched the logger to debug level and it only logs is bellow.

```
2019-06-21 17:46:09,182 DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - Executing aggregation: { "aggregate" : "event_record" , "pipeline" : [ { "$group" : { "_id" : "$domain" , "totalRelatedEventCount" : { "$sum" : "$relatedRecordCount"} , "totalMainEventCount" : { "$sum" : 1}}}] , "explain" : true}
```

If I use the pipeline in robo3t the result is expected as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little investigation with debugging I found a silly solution. I get my data in `AggregationResults.rawResults` with key "firstBatch" and `returnPotentiallyMappedResults` method in `MongoTemplate` class trying to get it with "result" key. So I have written a CustomMongoTemplate and ovverride the `returnPotentiallyMappedResults`